# SonarQube not showing coverage all test layer

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines, sonarqube-scan, dotnetcorecli

I create pipeline SonarQube in Azure DevOps

```
   - task: SonarQubePrepare@4
     inputs:
       SonarQube: 'SonaQube'
       scannerMode: MSBuild
       projectKey: 'mykey'
       projectName: 'projectname'
       projectVersion: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
       extraProperties: |
         sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=**/coverage.opencover.xml
         sonar.cs.xunit.reportsPaths=**/TestResults.xml
         sonar.exclusions=Persistence/Configurations/**, Persistence/**, Migrations/**, Entities/**/**, Program.cs, ConfigureServices.cs

   - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
     displayName: Restore
     inputs:
      command: restore
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      feedsToUse: config
      nugetConfigPath: nuget.Config

   - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
     displayName: Build
     inputs:
       command: build
       projects: '$(lowerProjectName).csproj'
       arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

   - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
     displayName: Build Test Project
     inputs:
       command: build
       projects: '**Test/**Test.csproj'
       arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

   - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
     displayName: Test
     inputs:
       command: test
       projects: '**Test/**Test.csproj'
       publishTestResults: false
       arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\ /p:CoverletOutputFormat="\"cobertura,opencover\"" -l:xunit --no-build'

   - powershell : |
       dotnet new tool-manifest --force
       dotnet tool install dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
     displayName: Install Report Generator

   - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
     displayName: Report Generator
     inputs:
       command: custom
       projects: '**Test/**Test.csproj'
       custom: reportgenerator
       arguments: '"-reports:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\coverage.cobertura.xml" "-targetdir:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\Reports" -tag:$(Build.BuildNumber) -reportTypes:htmlInline'

   - task: SonarQubeAnalyze@4
     displayName: 'Run Code Analysis'

   - task: PublishTestResults@2
     displayName: Publish Test Results
     inputs:
       testResultsFormat: XUnit
       testResultsFiles: '**/TestResults.xml'

   - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
     displayName: 'Publish code coverage'
     inputs:
       codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
       summaryFileLocation: '**/coverage.cobertura.xml'
       reportDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResults\Reports'
```

But it always shows me the test results of one layer
If I add "projects:'Application.Test/Application.Test.csproj'" show only coverage layer Applicaion
But I use "'**Test/**Test.csproj'" show only coverage layer Web

If I add "projects:'Application.Test/Application.Test.csproj'" show only coverage layer Applicaion
But I use "'**Test/**Test.csproj'" show only coverage layer Web